# Permission Denied in Accessing Package Within Spack

Tags: spack

I am trying to create a Quantum Espresso environment within Spack to run modeling simulations with the package libxc. In the process of creating a QE environment, I am trying to run the code

~/spack/var/spack/repos/builtin/packages/libxc

and am receiving a "permission denied: /Users/..." error.

I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

I am expecting to be able to patch the libxc-package into the environment to use with Quantum Espresso for more precise simulations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do here.  The files in `$SPACK/var/spack/repos/builtin/packages` are not the actual software, but rather recipes for how to build the software.  What were you trying to do when you tried to run `~/spack/var/spack/repos/builtin/packages/libxc`?

If you want to run with `libxc` or any other piece of software you need to install it first.  I would suggest checking out the [spack tutorial](https://spack-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to get started.